# SpeechClient.dll is giving XamlParseException

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

I am using SpeechClient.dll for speech recognition in dictation mode. Its giving me XamlParseException even when I am just creating an object from SpeechRecognitionServiceFactory class

```
using System;
using MicrosoftProjectOxford;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace OnlineRecognition
{

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    string m_primaryOrSecondaryKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["primaryKey"];
    private SpeechRecognitionMode m_recoMode = SpeechRecognitionMode.LongDictation;
    private bool m_isMicrophoneReco = true;
    private MicrophoneRecognitionClient m_micClient;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="MainWindow"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        m_micClient = SpeechRecognitionServiceFactory.CreateMicrophoneClient(m_recoMode, "en-us",
                                                                                        m_primaryOrSecondaryKey);
    }
}
}
```

I searched few msdn blogs for this error and got a page with exact error

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/611e7f6f-f664-4218-bbee-015990bb624e/speechclientdll?forum=mlapi

There someone suggested to run the code in windows 8 because the windows Speech Library has hard dependency on windows 8's network Stack. I followed and executed the code on windows 8 but same error persists. Can anyone help me with this error. Attached snapshots of details of XamlParseException on Win7 and Win8.

[image: Error on Win 7]
[image: Error on Win 8]

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.  I was running the code on a machine that was different than my development machine.  I installed the Visual C++ Redistributable Packages (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784), rebooted, and it resolved my issue.

I'm not sure if it will fix your issue or not, but it worked for me!  (Note that I installed them for Visual Studio versions 2013 and 2015.)